# Analyze and optimize crontabs

Tags: linux, unix, cron

Is there a tool to graph, analyze and help optimize crontab execution?

To clarify, I'm thinking of a tool which would generate a graph of when cron jobs are executed, and help the sysadmin reorganize them smartly.

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head, but it's Bank Holiday monday tomorrow, so I could have a go at writing one.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I've done is move cron jobs into a [structured job scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Job_Scheduler) in order to graph dependencies and gain visibility into the effects downtime windows.

Comment: That looks interesting but quite heavy to implement.

Comment: It was for a 1200-line crontab I was using... but yes, very heavy. I'd like to see something lighter-weight as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this is the functionality you'd like http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6673-PHP-Parse-crontab-schedule-and-generate-Gantt-charts.html

I can't vouch for the above, it is just the results of some web searching.

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of framework to assign a unique ID to each cron job and correlate that in the log file(s), and/or logging to a specific location to record runtime information (as opposed to the normal output log). It's not going to be trivial however you design it, but for small systems it is easy to eyeball this from looking at your crontabs and log files.

I assume you're not talking about small systems, though.

Comment: I like this idea and it could be relatively easily implemented in cron itself rather than a wrapper/framework. Just md5sum the crontab line for the unique identifier and track SIGCHILD to log stop times.

Answer (score 0):

A script for print all system tasks sorted by time

```
#!/bin/bash

CRONTAB='/etc/crontab'
CRONDIR='/etc/cron.d'

tab=$(echo -en "\t")

function clean_cron_lines() {
    while read line ; do
        echo "${line}" |
            egrep --invert-match '^($|\s*#|\s*[[:alnum:]_]+=)' |
            sed --regexp-extended "s/\s+/ /g" |
            sed --regexp-extended "s/^ //"
    done;
}

function lookup_run_parts() {
    while read line ; do
        match=$(echo "${line}" | egrep -o 'run-parts (-{1,2}\S+ )*\S+')

        if [[ -z "${match}" ]] ; then
            echo "${line}"
        else
            cron_fields=$(echo "${line}" | cut -f1-6 -d' ')
            cron_job_dir=$(echo  "${match}" | awk '{print $NF}')

            if [[ -d "${cron_job_dir}" ]] ; then
                for cron_job_file in "${cron_job_dir}"/* ; do  # */ <not a comment>
                    [[ -f "${cron_job_file}" ]] && echo "${cron_fields} ${cron_job_file}"
                done
            fi
        fi
    done;
}


temp=$(mktemp) || exit 1


cat "${CRONTAB}" | clean_cron_lines | lookup_run_parts >"${temp}" 


cat "${CRONDIR}"/* | clean_cron_lines >>"${temp}"  # */ <not a comment>

while read user ; do
    crontab -l -u "${user}" 2>/dev/null |
        clean_cron_lines |
        sed --regexp-extended "s/^((\S+ +){5})(.+)$/\1${user} \3/" >>"${temp}"
done < <(cut --fields=1 --delimiter=: /etc/passwd)

cat "${temp}" |
    sed --regexp-extended "s/^(\S+) +(\S+) +(\S+) +(\S+) +(\S+) +(\S+) +(.*)$/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t\7/" |
    sort --numeric-sort --field-separator="${tab}" --key=2 --key=1 |
    sed "1i\mi\th\td\tm\tw\tuser\tcommand" |
    column -s"${tab}" -t

rm --force "${temp}"
```